# Problem to run .bash scrpt

Tags: 14.04, bash, scripts

I am trying to run the following code:

```
/shared/Downloads/Chipre/processDataset_V2.bash myGraph_v3_for_GPT_v2_2.xml variables.properties "/shared/Downloads/Chipre/June" "/shared/Downloads/Chipre/GPT/June" ndvi
```

The first error I find is

```
bash: /shared/Downloads/Chipre/processDataset_V2.bash: Permission denied
```

Which I have solved by adding `sh`

```
sh /shared/Downloads/Chipre/processDataset_V2.bash myGraph_v3_for_GPT_v2_2.xml variables.properties "/shared/Downloads/Chipre/June" "/shared/Downloads/Chipre/GPT/June" ndvi
```

Now the error claims:

```
: not foundnloads/Chipre/processDataset_V2.bash: 3: /shared/Downloads/Chipre/processDataset_V2.bash: 
: not foundnloads/Chipre/processDataset_V2.bash: 7: /shared/Downloads/Chipre/processDataset_V2.bash: 
: not foundnloads/Chipre/processDataset_V2.bash: 10: /shared/Downloads/Chipre/processDataset_V2.bash: 
: not foundnloads/Chipre/processDataset_V2.bash: 14: /shared/Downloads/Chipre/processDataset_V2.bash: 
: not foundnloads/Chipre/processDataset_V2.bash: 17: /shared/Downloads/Chipre/processDataset_V2.bash: 
: not foundnloads/Chipre/processDataset_V2.bash: 20: /shared/Downloads/Chipre/processDataset_V2.bash: 
: not foundnloads/Chipre/processDataset_V2.bash: 23: /shared/Downloads/Chipre/processDataset_V2.bash: 
: not foundnloads/Chipre/processDataset_V2.bash: 26: /shared/Downloads/Chipre/processDataset_V2.bash: 
: not foundnloads/Chipre/processDataset_V2.bash: 29: /shared/Downloads/Chipre/processDataset_V2.bash: 
: not foundnloads/Chipre/processDataset_V2.bash: 30: /shared/Downloads/Chipre/processDataset_V2.bash: 
: not foundnloads/Chipre/processDataset_V2.bash: 34: /shared/Downloads/Chipre/processDataset_V2.bash: 
/shared/Downloads/Chipre/processDataset_V2.bash: 36: /shared/Downloads/Chipre/processDataset_V2.bash: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I have been doing some research on the forum and some people said that the .bash file has to start with the sheband line (which it does in my case. My first line is `#!/bin/bash`).

I think my problem is that I am not specifying properly the interpreting shell but I don't know how to solve it.

EDIT ---

If I try with `bash` and not `sh`

```
bash /shared/Downloads/Chipre/processDataset_V2.bash myGraph_v3_for_GPT_v2_2.xml variables.properties "/shared/Downloads/Chipre/June" "/shared/Downloads/Chipre/GPT/June" ndvi
```

The error claimed is:

```
/shared/Downloads/Chipre/processDataset_V2.bash: line 3: $'\r': command not found
/shared/Downloads/Chipre/processDataset_V2.bash: line 7: $'\r': command not found
/shared/Downloads/Chipre/processDataset_V2.bash: line 10: $'\r': command not found
/shared/Downloads/Chipre/processDataset_V2.bash: line 14: $'\r': command not found
/shared/Downloads/Chipre/processDataset_V2.bash: line 17: $'\r': command not found
/shared/Downloads/Chipre/processDataset_V2.bash: line 20: $'\r': command not found
/shared/Downloads/Chipre/processDataset_V2.bash: line 23: $'\r': command not found
/shared/Downloads/Chipre/processDataset_V2.bash: line 26: $'\r': command not found
/shared/Downloads/Chipre/processDataset_V2.bash: line 29: $'\r': command not found
/shared/Downloads/Chipre/processDataset_V2.bash: line 30: $'\r': command not found
/shared/Downloads/Chipre/processDataset_V2.bash: line 34: $'\r': command not found
/shared/Downloads/Chipre/processDataset_V2.bash: line 36: syntax error near unexpected token `$'{\r''
'shared/Downloads/Chipre/processDataset_V2.bash: line 36: `function normalizePath() {
```

The output of `ls -l /shared/Downloads/Chipre/processDataset_V2.bash` is:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 rus rus 2225 Feb 28 09:00 /shared/Downloads/Chipre/processDataset_V2.bash
```

Comment: It seems that your scrip don't have execute permissions. What is the output of `ls -l /shared/Downloads/Chipre/processDataset_V2.bash` ?

Comment: I have modified the question to show the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have written this on windows, and when you create a new line in windows it inserts `\r`, but bash doesn't understand that.

Look [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613800/how-to-convert-dos-windows-newline-crlf-to-unix-newline-n-in-a-bash-script) to see how to remove it.

Comment: All the lines that appear has error in the output are actually empty lines in the script. About line 36, could it be the the function declaration shoud be without the ()? Isn't it the problem related to `ls -l` and the fact that I have `-rw -r--r--`?

Comment: You could change the permissions so you don't have to write bash in front of the command, but it looks like there are more problems.
Try removing the \r as i suggested, that might fix the other errors, since it confuses the program.

Comment: The suggested solution on your link would be something like `tr -d '\015' <DOS-file >UNIX-file`. Any help on how to proceed? Don't have enough experience with Linux to understand the procedure

Comment: Make sure to save a copy of the original file first. Then write: 

`tr -d '\015' </shared/Downloads/Chipre/processDataset_V2.bash >/shared/Downloads/Chipre/processDataset_V3.bash`

This should work, if this is indeed the problem.

Comment: It seems this has solved the issue. Now I have another problem but is an internal error of the script on how it is importing the data. Thank you for your help